# Scroll full list to bring last item top with bottom empty space

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I want to scroll listview upto last item and bring last item in top of the listview with bottom empty space. For that i tried to add footer and update the height of the footer dynamically by subtracting listview last item height with listview height. But, i cannot get exact listview height.

Is there any other way to scroll full list to bring last item top with bottom empty space? Help me please.

Comment: How are you trying to get the listview's height?

Comment: Tried in this way ListAdapter adapter = list.getAdapter();list.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
                 MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));listviewHeight = list.getMeasuredHeight() * adapter.getCount() + (adapter.getCount() * list.getDividerHeight());

Comment: Where did you put this code? Remember onCreate and onResume still does not have the views drawn, so these will just return 0.